# Is it good practice to run a backend and a frontend server with express in NodeJS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am currently working on a simple NodeJS/AngularJS application and my current project looks like this:

```
/frontend/index.html <-- AngularJS home page
/frontend/js/app.js  <-- AngularJS app.js
/backend/package.json<-- NodeJS package.json
/backend/index.js    <-- NodeJS script
```

and I am only serving the backend API with my NodeJS express server while I open the frontend part directly (file://.../frontend/index.html) in my browser.

Is it good practice to serve both the "Backend API" and the frontend with NodeJS (e.g. with two express instances running) and how would I organize the code?

Comment: You don't need two express instances. Just use a static middleware to serve static files

Answer (score 1):

> while I open the frontend part directly (file://.../frontend/index.html) in my browser.

That is something you can only do on your own local computer.  You cannot do that for a regular web server that other people can use.  So, that is NOT considered a viable practice for a regular web server designed for other people on the internet to use.

With one line of code using `express.static()` middleware you can have your existing node.js server also serve all your static HTML files.  You do not need a separate process for serving the HTML files.  At super large scale, you might use something like an NGINX proxy to serve your static HTML files, but I don't see any reason for you to be going that direction now.  At this point, just have your existing node.js server use `express.static()` to serve your static files and stop using any `file://` references.

> Is it good practice to serve both the "Backend API" and the frontend with NodeJS (e.g. with two express instances running) and how would I organize the code?

No.  You've shown no reason why you would need two node.js instances.  Just use the one instance to serve both the API and the static HTML files.